# Syntax error when converting from float64 to integer

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use excel data in pandas and have to convert float64 data to integer type, but I keep getting Syntax errors. Please note, I am a complete novice to programming languages, so I'd appreciate as much help as possible - it's taken me a week just to figure out how to open my excel file in pandas, and now I'm having problems getting it into a format I can use in matplotlib. The code I have used follows, so I hope someone can help...

```
from pandas import ExcelFile
import pandas as pd
# Create ExcelFile object
xlsx = ExcelFile('filename.xlsx')
xlsx.parse(sheetname, parse_cols=6, index_col=None, na_values= ['NA']
# Convert float data types to integer
Spectral Type = Spectral Type.astype('int')
```

When I run this I get:

```
Spectral Type = Spectral Type.astype('int')
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong?

Is there a better way to access and use my Excel data so that I can create a graph in matplotlib?

Re my comment in response to unutbu, my data is of the form:

```
Type   Value1   time1  Value2   time2  Value3   time3

M0  8.87    41.11   8.41    41.11   8.16    65.78;
```

continuing with values from M1 to M6:

```
M6     13.95  4392.03  14.41 10395.13  14.66 25988.32
```

Running the script:

```
`from pandas import ExcelFile`
`import pandas as pd`
`# Create ExcelFile object`
`xlsx = ExcelFile('filename.xlsx')`
`xlsx.parse(sheetname', parse_cols=6, index_col=None, na_values= ['NA'])`
`df`
```

(with the addition of the column names specified in the parse action)

returns the following output:

`<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`
Int64Index: 11 entries, 0 to 10
Data columns:
Spectral Type                10  non-null values
Limiting magnitude (1.3")    10  non-null values
Exposure time @ 1.3", sec    10  non-null values
Limiting magnitude (2.0")    10  non-null values
Exposure time @ 2.0", sec    10  non-null values
Limiting magnitude (2.5")    10  non-null values
Exposure time @ 2.5", sec    10  non-null values
dtypes: float64(6), object(1)`

So, the questions I need to ask now are:

1. Is it necessary to change my data type for the Limiting magnitude and Exposure time columns, given that the data are decimal numbers?
2. I need to keep the Spectral Type column as it is; how do I do this?
3. What do I do to be able to put my data in the proper tabular format, so I can graph it?

Answer (score -1):

If `Spectral Type` is a column name in `xlsx`, then try:

```
import pandas as pd
# Create ExcelFile object
xlsx = pd.ExcelFile('filename.xlsx')
df = xlsx.parse('sheetname', parse_cols=6, index_col=None, na_values= ['NA'])
```

The `Spectral Type` column,

```
df['Spectral Type']
```

is of dtype `object` and contains values such as `M0`. These are probably strings. Whatever the case, the dtype can not be converted to `int`. This is why

```
df['Spectral Type'] = df['Spectral Type'].astype('int')
```

was raising an error. If instead, you wish to convert a column of dtype `float` to `int` then

```
df['Limiting magnitude (1.3")'] = df['Limiting magnitude (1.3")'].astype('int')
```

would work -- assuming I've got the name of the column correct.

---

> Is it necessary to change my data type for the Limiting magnitude and
>   Exposure time columns, given that the data are decimal numbers?

At the end of output you posted, pandas reports

```
dtypes: float64(6), object(1)
```

This says that of the seven columns in your DataFrame, 6 are of dtype `float64` and one is of dtype `object`. I'm guessing by the names of the columns that Limiting magnitudes and Exposure times are of dtype  `float64`, and Spectral Type is of dtype `object`.

If this guess is right, you should not need to change the type of the Limiting magnitudes and Exposure times if you want to manipulate them as `float64`s.

---

> I need to keep the Spectral Type column as it is; how do I do this?

I don't understand the question. Please elaborate?

---

> What do I do to be able to put my data in the proper tabular format,
>   so I can graph it?

Your data can be printed in a tabular format like this:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 7)
print(df)
```

To make a plot, you could use [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/). Pandas also has some [functions for plotting](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/visualization.html).

Comment: Apart from the syntax errors in the `xlsx.parse` line, the result doesn't seem to be bound back to `xlsx`, so isn't `xlsx` an `ExcelFile`, not a `DataFrame`?  I usually use the pattern `df = xlsx.parse(etc)`.

Comment: Oops, I wasn't reading this carefully enough. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Thanks to both unutbu and DSM, but I still can't get the data type converted. Here's what I tried:

Comment: Thanks to both unutbu and DSM, but I still can't get the data type converted. Here's what I tried: 'xlsx = pd.ExcelFile('filename.xlsx')' 'df=xlsx.parse(etc)'  # Convert float data types to integer. Column name is Spectral Type, so I tried my original 'Spectral Type = Spectral Type.astype('int')', and got the syntax error again, unutbu's suggestion didn't work either, finally I tried 'df.Spectral Type = df.Spectral Type.astype('int')' which also produced an invalid syntax error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I've just discovered that the column "Spectral Type" is an object. The other columns, which are float 64, have long names, eg "Exposure time @ 1.3",sec", or "Limiting magnitude (1.3")". Is this the reason I am getting invalid syntax errors?

Comment: Python variable names can not include spaces. That is one reason why `Spectral Type = ...` is not going to work. It sounds like the *string* `'Spectral Type'` is the name of a column in the DataFrame. That is why I suggested `df['Spectral Type']`. If it didn't work, please post a full traceback error message as an addendum to your question (they're hard to read in comments). We're flying blind here, so "it did not work" is just not enough information for us to help you :)

Comment: Hi unutbu, OK, but first I'll show you the type of data I'm trying to work with; it's probable that I don't need to convert most of it. The reason I thought I did, was from following various tutorials that told me I needed to.

Comment: Thanks unutbu, you've been most helpful. While waiting for your response I came across another method to achieve this by using the SQlite add-on in Firefox. Works a treat :) YouTube has a great video tutorial on how to do this.

Comment: However, I would still like to know how to avoid/fix the issues relating to your suggestions on how to display my data.

Comment: Hi unutbu, I've managed to resolve the problem. I parsed the file as an xls file instead of an xlsx file. I also removed the column 'Spectral Type', in case this was causing a problem. Not sure if both actions were necessary, but I've now been able to generate the graph to your third solution as per my related post. Thanks again for your help, and also to DSM